# Difference catalog category - default and layered

Tags: catalog, category, default

This is something I did not understand and could not find satisfying answers for.

1. What ist the difference between `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered` in `catalog.xml`?
2. When is `catalog_category_default`used? Does it have to be enabled somewhere?

All I've seen rendered is `catalog_category_layered` with the layered navigation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically if you activate "Is Anchor" under Category Design tab, you among other things also activate Layered Navigation. Layered Navigation means that instead of just displaying catalog list Magento also displays Filters (Prices, Categories, Dropdown Attributes and so on). Since different modes produce significantly different output there're two different page layouts.

`catalog_category_default` means no filters. `catalog_category_layered` means that there are filters as well.

Comment: great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

So the layout handles for the category view page are loaded in `Mage_Catalog_CategoryController::viewAction()`.

Beside all the other layouts  (`default`, `catalog_category_view`, `CATEGORY_{category id here}`), one of the the 2 you mentioned are added.

This is the line that adds it.

```
$update->addHandle($category->getLayoutUpdateHandle());
```

If you take a look at the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::getLayoutUpdateHandle()` you will see what layout handle is applied.

```
public function getLayoutUpdateHandle()
{
    $layout = 'catalog_category_';
    if ($this->getIsAnchor()) {
        $layout .= 'layered';
    }
    else {
        $layout .= 'default';
    }
    return $layout;
}
```

This means that if the category has the flag `is_anchor` set to `yes` then the `catalog_category_layered` handle is loaded. Otherwise `catalog_category_default` is loaded

Comment: in my case i checked the root category, category and sub category for `is anchor` filed and are well set to `yes` so in my catogory page, i have well the layered navigation But the layout handle is `catalog-category-view` and not `catalog-category-layered` like you explane !

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between catalog_category_default and  catalog_category_layered ,when  a category is loaded  `catalog_category_default layout it will calling Layered naviation i,e Filters attributes and categories of current Product Collection`, and catalog_category_layered  `will show its opposite`.

This setting is depending on is_anchor field of that current Category,if  `is_anchor is active then call  catalog_category_layered layout else call  catalog_category_default`